# Extracting Rails helpers methods to a separate class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to start creating objects for rails views helpers instead of using helpers (some kind of "roll your own" Cell::Object of Trailblazer or Hanami views). Everything works as expected until we start mixing blocks, and strangely enought we get different results at erb and haml templates!

This is a vainilla Rails v5.2 application, with only haml-rails added, as a simplification of the problem:

```
<h1>ERB</h1>

<%= bordered do %>
  <p>This works</p>
<% end %>

<hr />

<%= Builder.new.bordered do %>
  <p>This not works</p>
<% end %>
```

**app/views/home/erb.html.erb**

```
%h1 HAML

= bordered do
  %p This works

%hr

= Builder.new.bordered do
  %p This not works
```

**app/views/home/haml.html.haml**

```
module HomeHelper
  def bordered(&block)
    content_tag(:div, style: 'border: 1px solid black') do
      block.call
    end
  end
end
```

**app/helpers/home_helper.rb**

```
class Builder
  include ActionView::Helpers
  include ActionView::Context

  def bordered(&block)
    content_tag(:div, style: 'border: 1px solid black') do
      block.call
    end
  end
end
```

**app/presenters/builder.rb**

---

[image: ERB Result]

---

[image: HAML Result]

---

As you can see, when using the helper class the output gets wrong, but strangely enough different depending which template engine we are using.. Can somebody point me in the right direction to understand what is happending and how to do what we want? Thanks

Comment: Sample code here: https://github.com/vizcay/view_helper

Comment: Check out [NumberHelper#L199](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/number_helper.rb#L199) for a great example of how Rails actually handles such a thing behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Rails helpers are executed on the view itself, meaning that if you'll pass the view you can call the method on it in the same context:

Here is the solution for your problem:

```
class Builder

  def initialize(view_context)
    @view_context = view_context
  end

  def bordered(&block)
    @view_context.content_tag(:div, style: 'border: 1px solid black', &block)
  end

end
```

Now if you want to use your builder you'll have pass the view on creation, eg. `Builder.new(self).bordered` in the view itself.

Alternatively you can use the Rails [`TagBuilder`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L34-L112) ([doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag)), but you will still need the view context:

```
class Builder

  def initialize(view_context)
    @view_context = view_context
  end

  def bordered(&block)
    tag_builder.div(style: 'border: 1px solid black', &block)
  end

  private

  def tag_builder
    @tag_builder ||= ::ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper::TagBuilder.new(@view_context)
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I'm trying to escape the necessity to pass the view_context, precisely to create an encapsulated rails presenter.. but it looks like it is impossible! arggh